# cannot move vertical menu list to far left, it's under horizontal menu list

Tags: css, list, html

new to css. trying to create horizonal and vertical menus with list. 
my vertical list under the horizontal one goest to the next line, but it starts off where the horizontal menu ends like an indention tab. 
how do i get the vertical menu to go far left?

css and html code:

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 1.2em;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background-image: url(../images/listimage.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.clearfloat {clear:both;
  height:0;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
#horizontal_M  {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #272910;
  background-image: url(../images/btn.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
}
#vertical_M   {
  background-color: #EEF0E3;
  background-image: url(../images/sidemenubg.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="horizontal_M">
  <ul>
    <br class="clearfloat" />

    <li><a href="index.html">link 1/a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">link 4</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div id="vertical_M">
  <ul>

    <li><a href="index.html">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">link 4</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the container divs. Can style the `<ul>` instead.

Horizontal `<li>` should be `float: left;`

Vertical `<ul>` set `clear:left;`

Comment: i acutally floated the horizontal_M from your suggestion and it worked! i was floating and clearing all kinds of things, but still missing the right section to float until you suggested the horizontal <li> . float: left on horizontal_M did the trick. thanks a bunch!